# Performing operations on dplyr summaries

Tags: r, dplyr, summarize

Assume we have some random data:

```r
data <- data.frame(ID = rep(seq(1:3),3),
                   Var = sample(1:9, 9))
```

we can compute summarizing operations using `dplyr`, like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
data%>%
  group_by(ID)%>%
  summarize(count = n_distinct(Var))
```

which gives output that looks like this below an r markdown chunk:

```r
ID count
1   3           
2   3           
3   3
```

I would like to know how we can perform operations on individual data points in this `dplyr` output without saving the output in a separate object.

For example in the output of `summarise`, lets say we wanted to subtract the output value for `ID == 3` from the sum of the output values for `ID == 1` and `ID == 2`, and leave the output values for `ID == 1` and `ID == 2` like they are. The only way I know to do this is to save the summary output in another object and perform the operation on that object, like this:

```r
a<-
  data%>%
  group_by(ID)%>%
  summarize(count = n_distinct(Var))
a
#now perform the operation on a
a[3,2] <- a[2,1]+a[2,2]-1
a
```

`a` now looks like this:

```
ID count
1   3           
2   3           
3   4
```

Is there a way to do this in `dplyr` output without making new objects? Can we somehow use `mutate` directly on output like this?

Comment: `a[2,1]+a[2,2]-1` does not make sense to me: why are you adding `ID` to `count`? Why are you using matrix-indexing instead of frame-indexing (i.e., by-name)?

Comment: I echo the r2evans comment as well.  First I thought, it would be all rows except the last.  But, then your output would be different

Comment: You are correct my example does not make logical sense, it was actually a typo at first, but nevertheless it still worked as an effective example for my question of how to perform operations on individual locations within the output, therefore I chose to leave it as it was

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can add a `mutate` after the `summarise` with `replace` to modify the location specified in `list`

```
library(dplyr)
data%>%
   group_by(ID)%>%
   summarize(count = n_distinct(Var)) %>% 
   mutate(count = replace(count, n(), count[2] + ID[2] - 1))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
     ID count
  <int> <dbl>
1     1     3
2     2     3
3     3     4
```

---

Or if there are more than two columns, use `sum` on the `slice`d row

```
data%>%
   group_by(ID)%>%
   summarize(count = n_distinct(Var)) %>% 
   mutate(count = replace(count, n(), sum(cur_data() %>% 
          slice(2)) - 1))
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternative that does what you say you want (*"sum others"*) but not what you demonstrate.

```r
data %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarize(count = n_distinct(Var)) %>%
  mutate(count = if_else(ID == 3L, sum(count) - count, count))
# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#      ID count
#   <int> <int>
# 1     1     3
# 2     2     3
# 3     3     6
```

or, if there are other `ID`s that should not be included in the sum, then

```r
data %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarize(count = n_distinct(Var)) %>%
  mutate(count = if_else(ID == 3L, sum(count[ID %in% 1:2]), count))
```